# How to compare or normalize two sets of probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

I'm not sure how to ask this so I've written two versions: the short version is a pure stats question and the longer version explains my application.

### *The short version:*

I have two sets of probabilities. The first set has a range from $5.8\times 10^{-3}$ to $2.52\times 10^{-9}$ and the second ranges from $3.51\times 10^{-4}$ to $1.59\times 10^{-6}$. Both sets have a quasi-logarithmic distribution. The sets are not the same length. The sets are comprised of similar data but have different ranges due to the sample sizes.

I need to normalize the probabilities somehow so that I can compare my input data against both. How do I do this? (remember I am a stats newbie!)

If you need more info, please read the longer version:

### *The longer version:*

I am writing a software application that tries to predict the word a user is typing before he/she is finished. I have two source "dictionaries":

1. The first is a list of individual words ("singlets") + a count (the number of times the word appears in a corpus). It contains around 65,000 unique English words.
2. The second is a list of word triplets (e.g. "one of the") and the count of each triplet in a similar corpus. This list contains the most common 100,000 English triplets. Although it has more entries than the first list, it has far fewer unique words.

The probability of a dictionary entry is: $\frac{\mathrm{count}}{\sum \mathrm{count}}$

Both lists have quasi-logarithmic probability distributions, as you can imagine.

I must predict words as the user is typing. For example, if the user just typed "one of t", my goal is to predict what the third word might be. The reason I use both lists is because the triplet list provides more accuracy but the singlet list has more unique words. He might be typing a common triplet like "one of the" or he might be typing an uncommon triplet like "one of tomorrow's". As a result I need to combine results from both lists.

My result set is the most common singlets that start with "t" and the most common triplets that start with "one of t", sorted by probability. The problem is the probability ranges are very different (see above) due to the different sizes of the corpora and the nature of singlets vs. triplets, so my results are usually skewed toward one list or the other. I don't fully understand the mathematics behind this, but the bottom line is that the predictions are screwy.

Comment: I suspect that perhaps what you are calling probabilities are not actually probabilities, or at least they might not be *conditional* probabilities conditioned on the known information.  For instance, I'm pretty sure the probability in English of "the" being the third word, given that "one of t" has appeared, must be way higher than any probability in your supposed ranges.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, "the" has a high conditional probability in the triplet set given the input "one of t". However is there a conditional probability in the singlet set given there is no context? BTW "one of t" may have been a poor example because "the" would have a very high probability in both sets. A better example is "i don't th" in which case "the" has a very low (conditional?) probability in the triplet set ("think" has the highest), even though "the" is a more common word than "think" overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great problem!!

And the long + short version is a very good way of describing the problem!! (+1)

I would use condtional probabilities, which may require some computation on the fly. Following up on your example, you would normalize the triplets by the total probability of 'one of t' *i.e.* the sum of the probabilities of all the triplets that start by 'one of t' do the same for the singlets, ie the sum of all the probabilities of the singlets that start with 't'. This should scale your probabilities nicely and in a meaningful way.

So, to sum up, the updated probability of a word starting with $abc$ (say) is:

$$ P^*(word|abc) = \frac{P(word)}{ \sum_{w \in A} P(w) },$$

where $A$ is the set of words that start with the letters $abc$.

Comment: Thanks Gui! I think I understand your answer but not the formula, particularly the denominator. Also there are many singlets that aren't in the triplet set... how do I factor them in? Also. my app has to run on a mobile device so computing all those probabilities in real-time (between keystrokes!) is impossible. I could pre-compute but then there won't be enough memory to store them all. Ideally I would use a triplet set with every possible triplet, then I wouldn't need the singlets, but that set would also be too large. Is there a simple mathematical way to map P(triplet) <--> P(singlet)?

Comment: I tried to clarify the formula. To solve your speed problem, you need to put your probabilities in a **tree**. That will do wonders!! This is an idea I had some time ago to perform massive multiple replacement, we can talk the detail some other place if you want. I you have space for the words, you should have space for the the nodes of the tree. Computing these scores will be the ratio of the prob of the children node to the prob of the current node which you can probably compute between key strokes. And you can merge triplets and singlets in the same tree, their probabilities will be scaled.

Comment: They are already in a tree. :) Two separate radix tries, to be exact. But I am still lost as how to perform the multiple replacement and probability scaling. I would very much appreciate it if we could discuss it. Thank you!

Comment: Write me a mail, you will find my address on my profile.